# wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) on = image_tag 'home1.jpg'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm upgrading an application from rails 4.2 to 7.0.

I've already upgrade my gems, but when I try to access to localhost it returns an error like

wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)

on line

`= image_tag 'home1.jpg'`

Also I have an admin page which doesnt include images, but it returns the same error but on line:

`= stylesheet_link_tag    "admin", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => "reload"`

This is my actual gemfile:

```
`source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 7.0.8'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 6.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 5.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.11'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'slim-rails'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.2.0'

gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'

gem 'rails-i18n', '~> 7.0'

gem 'devise', '~> 4.9'

gem 'simple_form', '~> 5.2'

gem 'kt-paperclip', '~> 7.2'

gem 'active_type'

#gem 'nokogiri'
#gem 'premailer-rails'

gem 'sucker_punch', '~> 1.0'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  # gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 4.2'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring', '~> 4.1'
end

gem 'sprockets', '~> 3.7.2'
gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.17'
  gem 'rvm-capistrano', require: false
  #gem 'capistrano-local-precompile', require: false
end
gem 'puma'
gem 'mysql2', group: :production`
```

`
Trace:

```
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
json (1.8.6) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `initialize'
json (1.8.6) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `new'
json (1.8.6) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
execjs (2.9.1) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:69:in `extract_result'
execjs (2.9.1) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:40:in `exec'
execjs (2.9.1) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:15:in `initialize'
execjs (2.9.1) lib/execjs/runtime.rb:68:in `new'
execjs (2.9.1) lib/execjs/runtime.rb:68:in `compile'
execjs (2.9.1) lib/execjs/module.rb:27:in `compile'
coffee-script (2.4.1) lib/coffee_script.rb:50:in `context'
coffee-script (2.4.1) lib/coffee_script.rb:78:in `compile'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/coffee_script_processor.rb:21:in `block in call'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/cache.rb:85:in `fetch'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/coffee_script_processor.rb:20:in `call'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:200:in `dfs'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:134:in `block in find'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `each'
sprockets (3.7.2) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `find'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:53:in `each'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:53:in `map'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:53:in `precompiled_assets'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:38:in `asset_precompiled?'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:266:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:368:in `precompiled?'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:372:in `raise_unless_precompiled_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:349:in `find_debug_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:230:in `block in lookup_debug_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:243:in `block in resolve_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:242:in `each'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:242:in `detect'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:242:in `resolve_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:229:in `lookup_debug_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:171:in `block in stylesheet_link_tag'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:170:in `map'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:170:in `stylesheet_link_tag'
app/views/layouts/admin.html.slim:7
actionview (7.0.8) lib/action_view/base.rb:244:in `public_send'
actionview (7.0.8) lib/action_view/base.rb:244:in `_run'
actionview (7.0.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `block in render'
activesupport (7.0.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208:in `instrument'
actionview (7.0.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:361:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (7.0.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:155:in `render'
actionview (7.0.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:76:in `block in render_with_layout'
activesupport (7.0.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (7.0.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (7.0.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
actionview (7.0.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:74:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (7.0.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:59:in `render_template'
actionview (7.0.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:11:in `render'
actionview (7.0.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:61:in `render_template_to_object'
actionview (7.0.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:29:in `render_to_object'
actionview (7.0.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:117:in `block in _render_template'
actionview (7.0.8) lib/action_view/base.rb:270:in `in_rendering_context'
actionview (7.0.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:116:in `_render_template'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:216:in `_render_template'
actionview (7.0.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:158:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:141:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:27:in `render'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:139:in `render'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in render'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/benchmark.rb:311:in `realtime'
activesupport (7.0.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14:in `ms'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:22:in `block in render'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:91:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (7.0.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:34:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:21:in `render'
responders (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:245:in `default_render'
responders (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:175:in `to_html'
responders (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:168:in `respond'
responders (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:161:in `call'
responders (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:216:in `respond_with'
devise (4.9.2) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:14:in `new'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:215:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:165:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (7.0.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:107:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:233:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:23:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:67:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (7.0.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (7.0.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (7.0.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:66:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:259:in `process_action'
activerecord (7.0.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:151:in `process'
actionview (7.0.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:188:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:251:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:18:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:48:in `serve'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:852:in `call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:38:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:36:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:704:in `call'
activerecord (7.0.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:638:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.0.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:99:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:28:in `call'
web-console (4.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
railties (7.0.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:40:in `call_app'
railties (7.0.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.0.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (7.0.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
activesupport (7.0.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
railties (7.0.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:93:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:23:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:138:in `call'
railties (7.0.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in `call'
puma (6.4.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:272:in `call'
puma (6.4.0) lib/puma/request.rb:100:in `block in handle_request'
puma (6.4.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:378:in `with_force_shutdown'
puma (6.4.0) lib/puma/request.rb:99:in `handle_request'
puma (6.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:443:in `process_client'
puma (6.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:241:in `block in run'
puma (6.4.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:155:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Any clue why is this happening?

Comment: Did you upgrade from 4.2 to 7.0 with one step? Probably it's better to do it step-by-step. Also it's better to add error stack trace to the question

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the errors, I guess its a compilation error. Maybe you should try migrating it again to ensure nothing breaks as upgrading gems is simply not the right way to upgrade to Rails 7.

There is an official upgrade guide to do it in a slow and steady way as in Rails 7, things have changed alot when it comnes to javascript compiler.
To name few -

1. Webpacker is retired
2. You need to decide how you need to bundle the JS FILES - import maps/jsbundling/shakapacker(which i use)

To know in depth, check this - [Javascript in Rails 7](https://gist.github.com/rstacruz/ea58ff0277b5e0b5938e86ea2d9571ba)

Also to get a ready to use [RAILS 7 SAMPLE APP](https://github.com/mike1011/referrals), you can cloen this repo and start adding your own code.

[Migrate to rails 7](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#the-upgrade-process)